# Writing a TAR file header - need validation

Tags: .net, format, tar

In .NET on windows I've tried a couple of open source tar libraries to write a tar archive (directly from memory, the input files never actually exist).

They produce tar files that can be parsed and extracted by the tar libraries but programs like 7zip report that the tar is an error.  Also gtar on Unix is throwing errors.

I'm not getting any specific feed back in the error messages, so I don't know what is wrong.

I have tried writing the tar files directly using the tar spec on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format), but that yields the same situation.

Does anyone know of a good util that can validate and tell me specifically what is wrong with the tar files I'm generating?

Here's my custom code for writing the archive. At the end of the archive I write 2 512 length blocks of nul as a terminator.  Note, that this code generates an archive that extracts fine using this opensource lib: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/
but like i said, it appears invalid to 7zip and gtar on unix.

```
public static void WriteTarEntry(string filename, byte[] data, Stream outputStream)
    {
        WriteTarEntryHeader(filename, data.Length, outputStream);
        WriteTarEntryData(data, outputStream);
    }
    static void WriteTarEntryHeader(string fileName, int fileSize, Stream outputStream)
    {
        var header = new byte[512];
        WriteStringToByteArray(fileName, header, 0, 100);
        WriteStringToByteArray(fileSize.ToString(), header, 124, 12);
        var unixTime = Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        WriteStringToByteArray(unixTime, header, 136, 12);
        WriteStringToByteArray("0", header, 156, 1);
        WriteStringToByteArray("ustar ", header, 257, 6);
        WriteStringToByteArray(" ", header, 263, 2);

        WriteStringToByteArray(Environment.UserName, header, 265, 32);
        WriteStringToByteArray(Environment.UserDomainName, header, 297, 32);

        WriteStringToByteArray("        ", header, 148, 8);
        var checksum =  Convert.ToString(header.Sum(b => b), 8).PadLeft(6, Char.Parse("0"));
        WriteStringToByteArray(checksum, header, 148, 6);
        header[148 + 6] = 0;
        header[148 + 7] = 32;
        outputStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
    }

    static void WriteStringToByteArray(string value, byte[] array, int start, int maxWidth)
    {
        var len = Math.Min(maxWidth, value.Length);
        var sourceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceBytes, 0, array, start, len);
    }


    static void WriteTarEntryData(byte[] data, Stream outputStream)
    {
        int totalBytes = 0;
        while (totalBytes < data.Length)
        {
            totalBytes += 512;
        }
        var alldata = new byte[totalBytes];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, alldata, 0, data.Length);
        outputStream.Write(alldata, 0, alldata.Length);
    }
```

Comment: What open source libraries are you using? Can you post some example code of what you've tried?

Comment: I'd be careful with doing the casting of `char` to `byte`; use `Encoding.ASCII` to convert a string to bytes instead.

Comment: I believe GNU tar (and possibly others) use some extensions to the original format, such that GNU tar can read all files created by the original, but that the original may not be able to read files created by GNU tar. I don't know that this helps, but it's a point of data.

Comment: ok makes sense. I will give that a try. Though I do encode the char data as ASCII beforehand...

Comment: made a change to WriteStringToByteArray to use ASCII encoding.  no difference.  I'm not writing any uid groupid, so I wonder if that is an issue.  I will play around - if anyone thinks of anything else, please let me know - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I managed to solve this one...  I found this post here: http://www.3dartist.com/WP/formats/index.html#tar

This reminded me that the date/time and file size all have to be in base-8 (i'd done the checksum, but not those two).

After making that fix it works fine.  Given this error, I'm kind of surprised the archive was parsable by open source library at all.

Here are the changed lines of code to the above:

```
static void WriteTarEntryHeader(string fileName, int fileSize, Stream outputStream)
    {
        var header = new byte[512];
        WriteStringToByteArray(fileName, header, 0, 100);
        WriteStringToByteArray(Convert.ToString(fileSize, 8), header, 124, 12);
        WriteStringToByteArray(0x1ff.ToString(), header, 100, 8);
        var unixTime = Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
        WriteStringToByteArray(Convert.ToString(unixTime, 8), header, 136, 12);
```